# BOOT RECEIVER filtered for package

Tags: android, receiver

I have been looking at some of the answers regarding boot receiver but none address my issue. I have added all solutions in my code.

I want to receive boot completed on android OREO which so far is the device that is not working. Here is the full implementation

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    //inside application
    <receiver
        android:name="com.anb.lucem.reminder.services.BootReceiver" 
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**BootReceiver.java**

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String TAG = "com.lucemanb.reminderapp.boot";

    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Boot Completed");
    }
}
```

This is working fine below API 26 but Oreo Seems to have a different approach

```
    09-10 16:45:55.792 848-873/? D/AppLockLoader: isAppLocked: packageName=com.anb.lucem.reminder, isLocked=false
09-10 16:45:57.860 657-951/? D/ProcessManager.AS: *** Skip {com.anb.lucem.reminder} to receive broadcast.
09-10 16:45:57.860 657-951/? D/BroadcastQueue: *** Not launch app com.anb.lucem.reminder/10130 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x9000010 (has extras) } from null/1000.(AutoStart limited)
```

Is there something am doing wrong?

Comment: I have sent an answer to your question yesterday, if it worked accept it if it did not notify me

Comment: sorry @BAHMAN I didn't update, it did not work. am still getting the same log. do you have any other suggestion

Comment: maybe your device has an app (App Lock Loader) which prevents your app to get boot broadcasts. test this app on another device or uninstall that app locker.

Comment: okay, ill do so. thanks, you can test it too, you can view logcat. drive.google.com/open?id=1jnSqgHlpw5p1Dnh-KX8C909NRHvbzULQ

Comment: @Lucem Did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This code is tested and worked in Android 8.1 or below

manifest:

```
       <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

class:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

    public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        private static final String ACTION_QUICK_BOOT = "android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON";

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(null != intent) {
                final String action = intent.getAction();
                if (Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action) || ACTION_QUICK_BOOT.equals(action)) {

                    // here do what you want to do on boot
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This din't work for me on android 8. I'm using techno f1

Comment: @EdijaeCrusar as you can see in log of question this device has `AppLockLoader` and also you see this log: `Skip {com.anb.lucem.reminder} to receive broadcast` and this one: `Not launch app com.anb.lucem.reminder/10130 for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x9000010 (has extras) } from null/1000.(AutoStart limited)` this means "app locker loader" prevents this app to run at startup so he has to change the settings of app locker or uninstall that app

Comment: For my case, I'm receiving `Not launch app .... for broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x9000010 (has extras) } from null/1000.(AutoStart limited)`